# Equivalent of $ \int_1^x e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}} \mathrm dt $ when $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

How can I prove that:

$$ \int_1^x e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}} \mathrm dt \sim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xe^{-\sqrt{\ln(x)}}$$

without using l'Hôpital's rule ?

Integration by parts:

$$ \int_1^x e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}} \mathrm dt= xe^{-\sqrt{\ln(x)}}-1+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^x \frac{e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}}}{\sqrt{\ln(t)}}  \mathrm dt=xe^{-\sqrt{\ln(x)}}+o(xe^{-\sqrt{\ln(x)}})+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^x \frac{e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}}}{\sqrt{\ln(t)}}  \mathrm dt $$

So how can I show that $$ \int_1^x \frac{e^{-\sqrt{\ln(t)}}}{\sqrt{\ln(t)}}  \mathrm dt =o(xe^{-\sqrt{\ln(x)}}) $$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the change of variable $t=\mathrm e^{s^2}$, one sees that one must show that $I(u)\ll K(u)$ when $u\to+\infty$, with
$$
K(u)=\mathrm e^{u^2-u},\qquad I(u)=\int_0^uK(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
Assume that $u\gt1$ and pick $v$ in $(1,u)$. Since $K\leqslant K(v)$ on $(0,v)$ and $K\leqslant K(u)$ on $(v,u)$, 
$$
I(u)\leqslant vK(v)+(u-v)K(u)\leqslant uK(v)+(u-v)K(u).
$$
Assume that $v=u-w$ with $w\to0$ when $u\to+\infty$, then $(u-v)K(u)=wK(u)\ll K(u)$ and
$$
K(v)=\mathrm e^{u^2-2uw+w^2-u+w}\leqslant\mathrm e^{u^2-u-uw}=K(u)\mathrm e^{-uw},
$$
for every $u$ large enough. Hence $uK(v)\leqslant u\mathrm e^{-uw}K(u)\ll K(u)$ for every choice of $w$ such that $w=o(1)$ and $u=o(\mathrm e^{uw})$, for example $w=1/\sqrt{u}$. QED.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer!